Https over CludflareD Tunnel with custom Comodo SSL Certificate?
I have read many similar topics but none of them helped me.
How do I configure Https through CludflareD Tunnel with my custom Comodo SSL Certificate.
I have been working fine with Universal SSL for a long time, but now I need to use my own Comodo SSL Certificate. And buying Business subscription to manage custom certificate is too expensive for me.
I will have the following design
Cloudflare DNS => CloudflareD Tunnel => Proxy with Comodo SSL Certificate => Applications
And currently this working for me.
Cloudflare DNS with enabled Universal SSL => CloudflareD Tunnel => Http Proxy => Applications
So I have the following questions:

Which SSL/TLS encryption mode should I choose for this?
I understand I need to disable Universal SSL so that Cloudflare does not generate a certificate for me. Is that correct?
DNS Records what should be the Proxy status? Proxied or DNS Only?
What else do I need to configure so that I can see my site through https with my Comodo SSL Certificate?

